# asp.net client side vbscript getting javascript runtime error ?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vbscript

I have a asp.net web page that im creating. and have a vbscript as the client side script. and the application will be accessed only from IE so thats not an issue. I get a weird error when i click on a button which is supposed to execute the client side vbscript instead it throws me a javascript runtime error?.

Is there a way to configure this ?.

By the way im moving from a HTA to asp page if someone can direct me as to how to implement this will be appreciated.

This is the html code for the button element

```
 <input type = "button"  value = "Display" name = "Run_Button" onClick = "getvalue">
```

This is the code for the client side vbscript

```
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">

Sub getvalue
  some text
End sub
```

Am i missing something? further i added the below line at the start of the html document

```
<%@language="VBScript"%>
```

Comment: the error im getting is "JavaScript runtime error: 'getvalue' is undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBScript [is no longer supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in IE11's "edge" mode, which your page will be rendered in if you're specifying `<!doctype html>`. You'll need to make a few changes to your webpage.

First, add the following `<meta>` tag to your `<head>` section:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
</head>
```

Second, all event handlers are considered to use JavaScript by default, so you'll need to call your function in one of two ways:

1. Using JavaScript syntax (note the added `()` to `getvalue`):

   ```
   <input type="button" value="Display" name="Run_Button" onClick="getvalue()">
   ```
2. Explicitly specify that you'll be using VBScript (no need to use `()` on `getvalue`):

   ```
   <input type="button" ... onClick="getvalue" language="VBScript">
   ```